# How can I test IE10 on Mac?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing

How can I test web sites in IE10 on Mac?

Currently I am testing IE9 in VirtualBox with Windows 7 installed from [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575). I could not find similar image for Windows 8. [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) does not have IE10 eigher. Is there an easy way to test IE10 on Mac?

**Solution**

- Install Windows 7 in VirtualBox from [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image][3]
- In Windows 7, go to http://www.modern.ie and download IE10.

Comment: I believe IE10 comes for Windows 7 as well, these days. Check Microsoft's home page for details.

Comment: Previously posted on Stackoverflow... Like this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629142/how-can-i-test-ie10-on-mac (For minimal testing, you may wish to check out http://www.browserstack.com/test-in-internet-explorer as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft provides lots of useful tools and virtual machines at [modern.ie](http://modern.ie) and they included IE10 too. All you need to do is going to that site and download the right one for your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it online in the mac http://www.browserstack.com/test-in-internet-explorer